# Using awk to read every 5 lines from a file to a new file with name file_# where # is incremented based on the current iteration

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with 200 lines in it. I want awk to read every 5 lines and create a file for it (whose file name will be file_#).

When program reads the first 5 lines, it will create file_1 for these 5 lines. When program reads 6-10 lines, it will create file_2 for those 5 lines. This has to be done till it reaches the end of file.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried so far and the (incorrect) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected code; for sample inputs we only need to see 15-20 lines (perhaps 5-10 characters per line) and th resulting handful of files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `awk` or anything fancy. Using GNU [`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html):

```sh
split --numeric-suffixes=1 -l5 file file_
```

Comment: To start from 1 instead of 0, maybe `--numeric-suffixes=1` instead of `-d` (at least for GNU `split`)